# Z-index in script

Tags: javascript, z-index

This is my HTML code for showing my animated logo, however when button is clicked animation appears under next image, I would like to change the z-index so the animation appears over.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ms-1"          
onclick="changeimage2()">Turn on the dog</button></div>
```

this is my script:

```
function changeimage() {
document.getElementById('myImage').src='images/animatedlogo.gif';
}
```

how do I add zindex to the script file, or do I add it to the HTML code?
I have tried this:

```
function changeimage() {
     document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'images/animatedlogo.gif'.style.zindex='100';

}
```

Which doesn't work, I can't figure out where to define the zindex.

Thanks.

Comment: If this value does not need to be in any way dynamic, but the element in question always needs the same z-index - then it would really make more sense to do this via your stylesheet. If you need it dynamic, or set it in certain situations only - then see duplicate.

Comment: I am not sure if it would solve your problem or not, but you can use document.getElementById('myImage').style.zIndex = 'x';.